# Add hours and minutes to datetime using input fields?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to add hours and minutes to the datetime using inputfields.

the inputfields are within a flash application but they are similar to any other HTML input fields.

so for the sake of this question, I will be using HTML input fields.

currently I cannot even add the hours to the datetime, let alone the minutes!

**My PHP code looks like this:**

```
$myTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['myTime']);
$myMinute = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['myMinute']);

    $end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). ' + '.$myTime.' hours'));
```

**and my input fields are like so:**

```
    <input type="text" name="myTime" />
    <input type="text" name="myMinute" />
```

when I enter the `$end_date` into a MYSQL datetime field, I get this `1970-01-01 01:00:00`

but I thought, with my code above, it should be `today's date and time` + whatever amount's passed through `$myTime` ?

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try to just use the strtotime function and remove the outer date() call.

Comment: `echo date('c', strtotime('+2 hours'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. Change variables according to you

> ```
> $minutes_to_add = 5;
> $h_to_add = 5;
>
> $time = new DateTime(); //Here you can also pass your Dynamic Variable like DateTime($variable);
> $time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));
> $time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $h_to_add . 'H'));
>
> echo $stamp = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
//replace 3 with variable
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', $now));

//try to use some thing like $minutes = ($hours * 60) + $minutes;
// so you dont need to add separately.
// replace 10 with your variable
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+10 minutes', $now));
```